# How to make multiple `OR` and `AND` in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have been trying to retrieve data from a MySQL DB. The following query doesn't yield anything:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ENTITY_RELATIONSHIPS_TABLE 
WHERE ((SUBJECT_GUID = ? AND TARGET_GUID = ?) 
       OR (TARGET_GUID = ? AND SUBJECT_GUID = ?)) 
  AND RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_VALUE_ID IN (?)
```

Removing `((SUBJECT_GUID = ? AND TARGET_GUID = ?) OR (TARGET_GUID = ? AND SUBJECT_GUID = ?))` makes the query work meaning that it it the faulty part.

This works:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ENTITY_RELATIONSHIPS_TABLE 
WHERE RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_VALUE_ID IN (?)
```

This is how I append the prepared data values:

```
let todo = [
    relGUIDs[0], relGUIDs[1],
    relGUIDs[1], relGUIDs[0],
]  

for (let i = 0; i < relIdsArr.length; i++) todo.push(relIdsArr[i]);
```

How can I get the query (below) to work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ENTITY_RELATIONSHIPS_TABLE 
WHERE ((SUBJECT_GUID = ? AND TARGET_GUID = ?) 
        OR (TARGET_GUID = ? AND SUBJECT_GUID = ?)) 
  AND RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_VALUE_ID IN (?)
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with the problematic part of the query? Both clauses are and the same, and they do exactly the same, so maybe a little context would help to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(SUBJECT_GUID = ? AND TARGET_GUID = ?)` and  `(TARGET_GUID = ? AND SUBJECT_GUID = ?)` is the same thing because you always compare `SUBJECT_GUID` to `relGUIDs[0]` and `TARGET_GUID` to `relGUIDs[1]`, also, `todo` should have only **5** values and the fifth value should be an array.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
let todo = [
    relGUIDs[0], relGUIDs[1],
    relGUIDs[0], relGUIDs[1],
    relIdsArr
]
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem: `let todo = [
    relGUIDs[0], relGUIDs[1],
    relGUIDs[0], relGUIDs[1],
    relIdsArr
]`